# Cookie timing question

Tags: c#, .net

When I add a cookie through `Response.cookies.add(cookie);` My cookie will not be placed on the clients side until the client requests a page from my site. At the time of request .net will do some magic, place the cookie in the response and the client will store it. ***Is this true?*** If the above assumption is true I should be able to see unplaced cookies by `cookie = response.cookies("foo")`. ***Seems logical, but is it correct?***

To sum it up.

I am placing a cookie, then later in the code before the request is served I am checking if the cookie is in the `request.cookies("foo"`) if it is not I am checking the `response.cookies("foo")`. This method does not work. How would i go about reading a cookie before it is sent to the client side.

The actual question I need answered; **Is there a way to view a cookies information before I send it to the browser? Something along the lines of check if cookie is on browser if not do some other check to see if it is waiting to be sent.If it is waiting to be sent read data on it**
thank you very much.

Comment: I'd be kinda scared if you could place cookies on my machine before I request a page from your site..

Comment: You only have a `Response` instance when you're answering a `Request`. Still hard to see the actual question.

Comment: I think you're using cookies wrong. It's a client construct. You should only put/get things from the set just before you or the client needs them. Otherwise work with other in-process collections...

Comment: @henk updated question. Let me know if it is still unclear. Thank you for looking at it.

Comment: @Henk: Sounds like he wants to set some cookies in the `Response.Cookies` collection and then try to use them later during the same request.

Comment: Response.Cookies["foo"] doesn't return the cookie you added to the response?

Comment: @yuck. That is exactly what I would like to do.

Comment: @mikeRichards No. Response.cookies("foo") is empty at the time (20 lines of code later) i am trying to peek inside it

Comment: @gh9 It should. How is the cookie created?

Comment: var cookie As New HttpCookie("foo");
             cookie("bar") = "test;"
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

Comment: Just a quick note, that code is VB, but this question is tagged C# :)

Comment: @mike ya, i try not to expose vb to others if i dont have to. but it is forced on me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly then you want to add a cookie to `HttpResponse` at some point after receiving a request from a client. Then at a later point of processing the request you want to access the same cookie again.

This quote might help you:

> "After you add a cookie by using the `HttpResponse.Cookies` collection, the cookie is immediately available in the `HttpRequest.Cookies` collection, even if the response has not been sent to the client."

(from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.cookies.aspx)

I suggest you to process the cookie only at one point during the response. Thus you can check if it's available in `HttpRequest`, and if not then add it to `HttpResponse` and invoke your additional logic.

Comment: It seems I didnt understand fully on how to use multi-value cookies. Thank you very much for all your help guys/gals